# Como concatenar variables Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa para mi padre y estoy utilizando tkinter. El problema es que no se como concatenar varias variables de control para que a medida que voy escribiendo en un "entry" se ponga en un "label" de una determinada forma.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Label
raiz=Tk()
edi=StringVar()
def editorial(*args):
    edi.get()
edi.trace("w", editorial)
edi1=Label(raiz, text="Editorial", font=("Arial", 14))
edi1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(20,0), pady=(30,0), sticky="W")
edi2=Entry(raiz, font=("Arial", 14), textvariable=edi)
edi2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(20,0), pady=(30,0))
#esto seria una parte, se repite varias veces con nombres diferentes
cal2 = Label(raiz,) #aqui es donde se supone que cambia el Label pero no puedo concatenar mas de dos variables de control
cal2.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=(20,0), pady=(30,0))
```

Lo que quiero conseguir con esto es modificar un Label para que concatene varias variables de control, si es que se puede hacer

Comment: provee un [mre]. Lee [ask], [answer] y pasa el [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En python concatenas con el caracter `+`

```
var1 = 'Hola '
var2 = 'Mundo'
print(var1 + var2)
```

Ahora bien te doy un ejemplo comentado de como podrias concatenar en este caso dos variables de control asignadas a dos `Entry`:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Ejemplo")
window.geometry('350x200')

# Variables de control
texto1 = StringVar()
texto1.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=texto1: textChange()) # Cuando se modifica el texto pasa a mostrar la concatenacion en el metodoso textChange()
texto2 = StringVar()
texto2.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=texto2: textChange()) # Cuando se modifica el texto pasa a mostrar la concatenacion en el metodoso textChange()
textoLabel = StringVar()

# componentes
txtTexto1 = Entry(window, textvariable=texto1, width=25)
txtTexto1.grid(column=0, row=0)

txtTexto2 = Entry(window, textvariable=texto2, width=25)
txtTexto2.grid(column=0, row=1)

lbl = Label(window, textvariable=textoLabel)
lbl.grid(column=0, row=2)

# Aqui mostramos los las variables de control texto1, texto2 concatenadas
def textChange():
    textoLabel.set("Este es el primero: " + texto1.get() + "\n Este es el segundo: " + texto2.get())

window.mainloop()
```

Ahh y no olvides que si quieres concatenar una variable que no sea `string` debes utilizar el método `str()` si no la usas obtendras otro error.

Ahora bien, en [éste enlace](https://python-para-impacientes.blogspot.com/2016/02/variables-de-control-en-tkinter.html) puedes encontrar información que posiblemente te sirva.

Espero sea de ayuda ;) Saludos

Comment: Ya he puesto un ejemplo del codigo que tengo, no se si necesitas mas

Comment: Quise utilizar un ejemplo con tu código, pero mejor intente hacer uno simple con dos componentes `Entry`, espero hacerme entender con éste ejemplo